# Deserialize JSON String into array or list

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement of deserializing JSON string and store it into a list or an array. Hence have used bellow give code

```
dynamic jr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(paramList);

foreach (var item.Value in jr)
{

}
```

**String value in paramList is like**

```
{"0":["1234","2222","4321","211000","90024","12","2121","322223","2332","3232"],"1":["0856","6040222","175002","23572","","","","","",""]}
```

**String value in item.Value is like -**

```
{[  "1234",  "2222",  "4321",  "211000",  "900224",  "12",  "2121",  "322223",  "2332",  "3232"]}
```

Hence kindly help me to iterate this string, so that i can put into an array or list.

Thanks

Comment: Check out this question. Sounds similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp

Comment: Note that `{[ ... ]}` is not valid Json. You'd need just the array (`[...]`) or a key (`{"key": [ ... ]}`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
var jr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(paramList);

foreach (var item in jr)
{
     // item.Value
}
```

**Update 1:**

Now if you only want to get all values into a list, you can use the following-

```
var allValues = jr.SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but receiving an error - Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: @dipak Please check again

Comment: Thanks, it also worked for me, but kindly let me know , how to put "item" which  into an List. For eg.

foreach (var item in jr)
{
    // Some thing like bellow
     // List.add( item.Value)
}

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if that works for you.